# How to provide custom order to LazyGridLayout?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

By default LazyVerticalGrid fills from left to right (assuming span 3) in following order:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

How to change direction to from top to bottom:

```
1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort the list before submitting it to the grid with an extension function.

```
fun <T> List<T>.customGridOrder(columnCount: Int): List<T> {
    val rowCount = (size + columnCount - 1) / columnCount
    val resultList = mutableListOf<T>()

    for (row in 0 until rowCount) {
        for (col in 0 until columnCount) {
            val index = col * rowCount + row
            if (index < size) {
                resultList.add(this[index])
            }
        }
    }

    return resultList
}
```

And then use it in your LazyVerticalGrid

```
val reorderedList = (0..34).toList().customGridOrder(3)
   LazyVerticalGrid(
      columns = GridCells.Fixed(3),
         content = {
           items(reorderedList) { item ->
             Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                  .size(32.dp)
                  .border(1.dp, Color.Red),
                   contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                ) {
                    Text(text = "$item")
                  }
           }
       }
   )
```